# Include a (header-only) library in an autotools project

Tags: c++, build-process, autotools, autoconf, automake

I want to integrate a header-only C++ library in my Autotools project. Since the library uses Autoconf and Automake, I use [`AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS`](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/autoconf/Subdirectories.html) in `configure.ac` and added the library dir to the `SUBDIRS =` line in `Makefile.am`.

My question is: how do I prevent the header library from being installed by `make install`? I'm building a single binary, so my users don't need these headers.

I'd prefer not to tamper with the library, so I can fetch upgrade by just untarring the new version.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea.

Move all the third-party libraries you do not want to see installed into a subdirectory called `noinst/`.  So for instance if you want to ship your project with something like Boost, unpack it into the directory `noinst/boost/`.   Use `AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS([noinst/boost])`.  Inside `noinst/Makefile.am`, do something like this:

```
SUBDIRS = boost
# Override Automake's installation targets with the command ":" that does nothing.
install:; @:
install-exec:; @:
install-data:; @:
uninstall:; @:
```

The effect is that whenever some of the recursive "make install*" or "make uninstall" commands are run from the top-level directory, the recursion will stop in `noinst/` and not visit its subdirectories.  Other recursive commands (like "make", "make clean" or "make dist") will still recurse into the subdirectories.

You could of course override `install:` and friends directly into the third-party package, and avoid the extra `noinst/` directory.  But if you are like me, you don't want to tamper with third-party packages to ease their update.
Also a nice property of the above setup is that if someone goes into `noinst/boost/` and decide to run `make install`, it will work.  It just does not occur by default when they install your package.

Answer (score 1):

just came across a similar problem and found the solution in the [automake manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Headers.html):

> noinst_HEADERS would be the right variable to use in a directory containing only headers and no associated library or program

Andreas

Comment: This will result in the ```make install``` command installing the noinst headers alongside everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `SUBDIRS` then. The following hack may work:

```
all-local:
        ${MAKE} -C thatlib all
```

Of course it would be best if the library remained in its own directory outside of your project, and you just point to it via CFLAGS/LIBS flags.

Comment: I'd love to keep it outside of my tree, but I'm trying to cut down on the external dependencies. Thanks, will try this.

Comment: Doesn't work. This builds the library after my program, which obviously won't work.